# How to use Google Cloud Translate API with C++

Tags: c++, google-api, raspberry-pi

I'm very new for C++, cmake, and Google Cloud APIs. I want to use Translate API with C++ for text translation on Raspberry Pi but I cannot find client library for C++ here.

https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries

I do research for a day and found this.

https://google.github.io/google-api-cpp-client/latest/

I confused because first url mentioned about older version.

1. Anyone know is this latest version ?
2. If it 's latest version where can I find example for using Translate API in C++ ?
3. If it's not, how can I use this api with C++ ?
4. Can I use this api with python and call python from C++ with Boost ?

Comment: and I also tried to use this too.
https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client